# How Count Korean Word Block using Unix/Linux Commands?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, wc

Korean consists of word blocks (e.g., 가, 나, 다 라, etc.).  I need a way to
count these word blocks.  For instance, the word 바다 (sea) should return 2. but

`wc -w` will return 1

`wc -c` will return 7

So these options won't work for me.  I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

`바다` encoded as UTF-8 is 6 bytes long. If you want to count characters, use `wc -m`:

```
$ printf "바다" | wc -c
       6
$ printf "바다" | wc -m
       2
```

Comment: okay, so subtracting wc -w from wc -m should work to count the block. great.  thanks.

Comment: @김은기: They're all off by 1 because `echo` appends a newline, sorry if that wasn't clear. See my update.